# Removing listener on element where in addEventListener were pasing arguments

Tags: javascript

How can I removeEventListener like this? I know that in move function in addEventListener I passed an annomous function, but i have to pass some arguments there. How can I resolve this?

```
move = (id) => {
    roadFields.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.handleRoadField(id, matrixBoard, e));
    });
};

handleRoadField = (id, matrixBoard, event) => {
    if (true) {
        roadFields.forEach(el=>{
            el.removeEventListener('click', this.handleRoadField);
        })
    } else {
        console.log('X');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining an `onClick` function and using it in both methods:

```
move = (id) => {
    roadFields.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    });
};

handleRoadField = (id, matrixBoard, event) => {
    if (true) {
        roadFields.forEach(el=>{
            el.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
        })
    } else {
        console.log('X');
    }
};

function onClick(e) {
    this.handleRoadField(id, matrixBoard, e);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help